# IDE указывает на ошибку в аннотации типов, но код работает правильно

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, типы

Есть правильно работающий кусок кода, который эквивалентен такому:

```
from typing import Optional


class Game:
    pass


def select(game: Game) -> Optional[Game]:
    vs: list[Game] = []
    next_games: list[list[Game, int]] = [[v, 0] for v in vs]

    if not next_games:
        return None

    next_games[0][1] = 0 # Тут

    return next_games[0][0]
```

PyCharm ругается на помеченную строчку, выдавая ошибку

> Unexpected type(s):(int, int)Possible types:(int, Game)(slice, Iterable[Game])

Подскажите, что она означает и как ее исправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, я нашел у себя ошибку: изначально вторая строчка метода `select` выглядела так (и ошибок не было):

```
next_games: list[tuple[Game, int]] = [[v, 0] for v in vs]
```

а потом я добавил помеченную строчку и поменял `tuple` на `list`. Что именно означает тип `list[Game, int]` я пока не понял, но подозреваю, что такая запись равносильна `list[Game]`. Правильно было бы написать

```
next_games: list[list[Union[Game, int]]] = [[v, 0] for v in vs]
```

Во-вторых, я, кажется, понял, как расшифровать само сообщение об ошибке. Для этого рассмотрим несколько примеров:

1. Заменим помеченную строчку на `next_games[0] = None`, тогда ошибка превратится в `Unexpected type(s):(int, None)Possible types:(int, list[Game, int])(slice, Iterable[list[Game, int]])`.
2. Заменим помеченную строчку на `next_games[0][vs[0]] = None`, тогда ошибка превратится в `Unexpected type(s):(Game, None)Possible types:(int, Game)(slice, Iterable[Game])`.

Интерпретирую это так: кортеж содержит в себе тип объекта в последних квадратных скобках и то, что стоит справа от знака равно.